# MySQL returning blank rows that contain HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a website and it has a table in MySQL that contains HTML for a couple of the rows. Every time I try to pull the data from the table, it returns "" for the rows containing HTML. The other rows, the ones without HTML, return the correct data. I escaped all double and single quotes, and the entire row is on a single line (no line breaks). I've been trying to solve the problem for a while now, and I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'exampleuser', 'examplepass', 'exampledb');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM Publications;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "\n<br>\"" . $row['Publications'] . "\"\n<br>";
}

?>
```

The HTML I'm putting in is very long so ill just paste the first section. Remember, no line breaks in the HTML. I just put them in so its easier to read.

```
<p class="MsoTitle"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">Publications</span><span style="font-
size: 12pt; font-weight: normal;"></span></p><p class="MsoNormal"><strong>
<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span></strong></p><p class="MsoNormal" 
style="margin-left: 0.25in; text-indent: -0.25in;">1. <strong><span style="font-weight: 
normal;">C. V. Krishnan and M. Garnett, Electrochemical Behavior of the Super Antioxidant, 
&alpha;-</span></strong></p><p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left: 0.25in; text-indent: 
-0.25in;"><strong><span style="font-weight:
```

And this is what's returned:

```
""
```

Comment: When you run the sql statement in phpMyAdmin (for example) does the offending fields appear or are they empty. (Just ruling out database problems first).

Comment: That's output syntax from MS Word. You've generated a page from it, correct?

Comment: Do this instead `echo "<br>" . $row['Publications'] . "<br>";`

Comment: also, like i said, mysql is not failing. it successfully connects. the rows that don't contain HTML work. it's just the rows with HTML that return the blank lines

Comment: ok, let me try it. actually, im converting an old ASP/MSSQL website into PHP/MySQL. im not really sure where the original data came from

Comment: results from removing "\"\n" from beginning and end of print: the page was completely blank. nothing was there at all.

Comment: The `<p class="MsoTitle"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">...` etc. - is that's what's inside your table/rows?

Comment: yes, that's just the first portion of what's inside the rows. there are probably 25,000 characters in just one of the columns and rows total

Comment: How did all that get there, is this recent? If so, I suggest you stop right there and rethink this. You're going to have to use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to "hopefully" fetch the data.

Comment: my boss is kind of forcing this project on me so i have no option, unfortunately. ill have to figure it out. ill look at prepared statements, although they dont appear to be useful for me in this case. the table is only 4 rows long

Comment: I suggest this then. Copy the MS Word stuff in a plain Notepad document, then re-paste it in DB; that's what I do. If there's styling to be done, I'll do it on the PHP side.

Comment: right, thats what i did. it returns it fine from the command line and phpmyadmin, but it doesnt return anything from php. even when using htmlentities()

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Including `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` - You sure you got the row correct? `Publications` is the same name as your table.

Comment: yes, it is the same name as the table. that isnt the problem is it?

Comment: the error reporting didnt yield anything at all. nothing changed. no errors

Comment: I don't think it would. Now, if your column and/or database is called `publications` with a lowercase `p`, that is an issue. Make sure they're named exactly as in your code; especially the column name.

Comment: im sorry, correction. new error: Notice: Undefined index: Publications in /home/garnett/public_html/test.php on line 14

Comment: Ah there ya go. Try using `publications` instead of `Publications` for your row/column. See how it's spelled in your table.

Comment: put it as an answer and ill accept it

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes so I can formulate a proper answer.

Comment: It has been done. Glad it got resolved, *cheers*

Comment: Just an added note. This http://demo.dsheiko.com/cleanmsword/ is what I use from time to time, in order to clean up MS Word tags. It works rather well (98%). You simply copy the MS Word CTRL-A for all text on the page, then paste into the box; should you ever want to try it out. You can also save from MS Word as a filtered HTML, but that doesn't take care of everything, but is pretty good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments exchanged between you and I. *(to close the question)*

> Notice: Undefined index: Publications in /home/garnett/public_html/test.php on line 14

This stems from your column being named `publications` and not `Publications`.

`$row['Publications']` and `$row['publications']` are *two different animals* altogether.

The column name is case-sensitive, and that is why you are not getting any data outputted.

Using error reporting at the top of your files, will reveal potential errors, if any are ever found in your code, as you have from a suggestive comment.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php**

  as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`

---

**Edit:**

As noted by E-Rock in a comment:

*"`mysqli_fetch_row()` returns an enumerated array of row data. You want `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` if you're expecting an associative array"*. Thanks E-Rock.

Comment: for reference, for some reason, it's telling me that my index is incorrect. i changed the name of the column to pubs, but none of the indexes are working. i var_dumped the entire row and all the data is there, so im referencing the data by index ($row[1]) instead of by name ($row['pubs']). not ideal, but its doing the trick for now. however, i appreciate the work you put into helping me figure it out. you solved enough of the problem to make it work.

Comment: @Deathstalker *Hm...*, that's quite bizarre; and you're quite welcome, was glad to have been of help.

Comment: @Deathstalker mysqli_fetch_row returns an enumerated array of row data. You want mysqli_fetch_assoc if you're expecting an associative array.

Comment: @E-Rock Thanks, I'll make an edit to that effect, with kudos to you.